# Can’t type capitals in the virtual console

Tags: keyboard-layout, virtual-console

I can’t type capital letters inside the virtual console using the shift key. If I use caps lock instead – it works. I noticed that the shift key acts like it’s the AltGr key (e.g. if I type Shift + q I get @), so I guess it's a keyboard layout problem.

I’ve got a german keyboard and I use Ubuntu 18.04 with the T3 keyboard layout. This works great outside the virtual console.

Comment: Sounds more like a keyboard configuration problem to me. What's the output of: `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

Comment: The output is `XKBLAYOUT=de
BACKSPACE=guess
XKBVARIANT=T3
`.

Comment: I see that that T3 layout is rather complex, so probably you are right that the issue is due to the layout. Don't know if there is a simple fix. Maybe add the basic German layout and use that in console.